# How do I turn off multitouch zoom in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, multi-touch

I'm using my wife's Macbook with the bigger multitouch track pad. Many times while in Safari, it thinks I want to zoom in and the page will zoom in. I want to just get rid of multitouch in Safari, or just disable the zoom feature in Safari.

It's nice to have multitouch in other applications like iPhoto, but it just causes problems in Safari.

Comment: In the past I've used Multiclutch for this, but Multiclutch is 32bit and doesn't seem to work on Snow Leopard. There doesn't seem to be viable replacement at this time.

Answer (score 1):

In the trackpad preference pane (System Preferences) there is an option to disable Screen Zoom.

There is an alternative. A small plugin, of sorts, that allows you to disable pinch zooming in Safari and Firefox.

http://cubeyellow.blogspot.com/2009/01/mac-book-pro-trackpad-zooming-and.html

Comment: but that turns it off for all applications. I would just like it turned off for Safari.